# Adding image to background for a popup window in Silverlight

Tags: c#, silverlight, silverlight-4.0, popup, background-image

**PROBLEM**
I want to add an image the background of a pop up. I am fairly new to Silverlight, so I apologize if there are some blatant, rookie errors in the following code

```
<Popup x:Name="MyPOP" HorizontalOffset="200" VerticalOffset="200" IsOpen="False"  >

        <StackPanel Width="800" Height="800" Background="Red">
            <Button Content="GO AMERICA" Click="Button_Click_1"  Width="100" Height="50" />
            <Canvas>
                <TextBlock Text="THESE COLORS DON'T RUN!!!!" />
            <Canvas.Background>
                <ImageBrush ImageSource="http://www.ilovethebronx.com/sites/default/files/events_pics/fireworks.jpg?1339518424"/>
            </Canvas.Background>

            </Canvas>
            </StackPanel>

    </Popup>
```

Any suggestions? Thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You simply need to set a Height on your Canvas, though I suspect that this is more like what you may be after:

```
<Popup x:Name="MyPOP" HorizontalOffset="200" VerticalOffset="200" IsOpen="True"  >

        <Grid Width="800" Height="800" Background="Red">
            <Grid.RowDefinitions>
                <RowDefinition Height="Auto" />
                <RowDefinition />
            </Grid.RowDefinitions>
            <Button Content="GO AMERICA" Click="Button_Click_1"  Width="100" Height="50" />
            <Border Grid.Row="1">
                <TextBlock Text="THESE COLORS DON'T RUN!!!!" />
                <Border.Background>
                    <ImageBrush ImageSource="http://www.ilovethebronx.com/sites/default/files/events_pics/fireworks.jpg?1339518424"/>
                </Border.Background>

            </Border>
        </Grid>

    </Popup>
```